# How to restore a weapon that won't show up, but is represented in Character data - I recently got Atlantis DLC...?

Tags: titan-quest-anniversary-edition

My character I have the most playtime with just lost her weapon upon my installation of the Atlantis DLC on Steam, and bootup.

I know her Staff is represented in the Player.chr, because I compared it with another character and he has his equipped staff in the same spot in the file...

What's wrong with the staff data for my character?

```
begin_block
baseName2Records\Item\EquipmentWeapon\Staff\C03_Frost01.dbr
prefixNameMRecords\Item\LootMagicalAffixes\Prefix\Default\Character_SkillMasteryF_01.dbr
suffixNameURecords\Item\LootMagicalAffixes\Suffix\Default\Character_AttributeIntelligence_02.dbr
relicName
relicBonus seed var1
relicName2 relicBonus2 var2
end_block
```

The seed, in Hex, is "C1 00 00 00 04 00 00 00"

---

If I need a hex editor to save her staff, I've got one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my staff was in Slot 1 of the two possible weapon slots, and I was looking at Slot 2. I somehow forgot that after not playing for so long.

So just had to switch weapon slots to get my staff back.